# Hibernate OnetoMany,ManyToOne Mapping Giving null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes called PurchaseList.java and PurchaseListItems.java

I have to map PurchaseList in PurchaseListItems

PurchaseList.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PurchaseListItems> purchaseListItems;
```

PurchaseListItems.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id")
private PurchaseList purchaseListId;
```

Everything is fine but i am getting null in pl_id. Please tell where i am wrong

Comment: JPA does not manage bidirectional relations. You have to establish the inverse relation yourself. Also note that your mappings define two independent unidirectional relations. See my explanation below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mapping actually defines two independent unidirectional relations. What you want is one bidirectional relation.The following code will establish the bidirectional relation

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "purchaseListId")
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PurchaseListItems> purchaseListItems;
```

The mappedBy attribute is necessary since there is no way for the provider to automatically determine that the specified relations actually form a single relation. One could use the Java type of the instance member but then what if you have multiple members of the same type. And there are many scenarios where you have two single relations. Example:

OneToMany: User -> ForumThread (the threads created by the user)

ManyToOne: ForumThread -> User (the user who closed the thread. obviously not necessarily the one who started the thread)

These are two independent relations and must be treated as such. You would be quite surprised if your persistence provide just made a bidirectional relation out of that just because the types and multiplicity matched.

Also note that bidirectional relations are not automatically managed by any JPA provider, meaning that the inverse side is not automatically updated/set in your object model and thus not in the db. You have to do that yourself. By the way, in all my projects bidirectional relationships were a pain in the ass and I think it is advisable to avoid them.

Comment: With hibernate4 (not sure about previous ver) mappedby and JoinColumn cannont be used together.

Comment: I have the same experience as https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047493/bennidi. If I will avoid bidirectional relationships and fetch everything "manually". I was finished two three times quicker.

Comment: I got error on using suggested solution --- org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @ JoinTable or @ JoinColumn: routines.WCAMessageAuditEntity.contexts

Comment: Sorry, the code is 7 years old. Maybe the standard and/or hibernate implementation changed in this particular aspect.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason mapped by didn't work for me with postgres sql and Hibernate4

Below mapping worked

**PurchaseList.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id",nullable=false)
private List<PurchaseListItems> purchaseListItems;
```

**PurchaseListItems.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id", nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false )
private PurchaseList purchaseListId;
```

Note: you have to use the Identity or Explicitly mention the Sequence for id columns for postgres.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Inside table the join column value is getting updated but in the entity object I am also getting value as null

Answer (score 2):

1. The @JoinColumn annotation belongs on the @ManyToOne side of the relationship - but not on the @OneToMany side - remove it from the @OneToMany side.
2. Cascade is used to cascade DELETE/READ/UPDATE operations..., but it does not automatically populate the ID column on the "child" side of a foreign key.  In fact, it doesn't populate the java references to objects on either side of the FK relationship. You need to manually setup relationship data on both sides of bidirectional relationships:

   myPurchaseListItem.setPurchaseList(myPurchaseList);
   myPurchaseList.setPurchaseListItem(myPurchaseListItem);

   From the JPA 2 spec:

   Bidirectional relationships between managed entities will be persisted based on references held by the owning side of the relationship. It is the developer’s responsibility to keep the in-memory references held on the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent with each other when they change. In the case of unidirectional one-to-one and one-to-many relationships, it is the developer’s responsibility to insure (sic) that the semantics of the relationships are adhered to.[29]

   It is particularly important to ensure that changes to the inverse side of a relationship result in appropriate updates on the owning side, so as to ensure the changes are not lost when they are synchronized to the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(PurchaseListItems item:purchaseListItemsList)
item.purchaseListId(PurchaseList);
```

This is what I missed when i am creating an object.

Thnaks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The jpa specification looks good, but verify you have given valid parent to child relationship in the database. If there is not a reference then it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "purchaseListId")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have populated ***purchaseListId*** with valid value (a created ***PurchaseList*** instance) when you create a ***PurchaseListItems*** value.

It's better to use ***mappedBy*** as below code to let many-side to maintian the relationship.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "purchaseListId")
@JoinColumn(name="pl_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PurchaseListItems> purchaseListItems;
```

Comment: No, its not working Henry,what you said above. I am missing something that what i dont know.

Comment: @sainath Can you explain what you mean by "Everything is fine but i am getting null in pl_id."?  you mean pl_id is null in database or in your loaded PurchaseListItems instance?

Comment: In database at the time of inserting it has to take the id from Purchases and it has to put in place of pl-id. But instead of this it is saving null.