# Hibernate 1:1 bidirectional mapping failed - nulled entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

Im currently trying to achive an 1:1 bidirectional mapping in hibernate. But I always get a nulled property in my child entity class, when I printed out.

```
Student{studentId=2, firstname='Benjamin', lastname='Peterson', email='benjamin.peterson@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@72906e, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=1, manufacturer='Apple', model='Macbook Pro Retina', student=null}}
Student{studentId=3, firstname='Daniel', lastname='Brooks', email='daniel.brooks@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@4d7a64ca, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=2, manufacturer='Lenovo', model='Thinkpad T420', student=null}}
Student{studentId=4, firstname='Jonas', lastname='Huber', email='jonas.huber@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@76ff68c5, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=3, manufacturer='Dell', model='XPS 15', student=null}}
Student{studentId=5, firstname='Julian', lastname='Maier', email='julian.maier@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@6418e39e, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=5, manufacturer='Lenovo', model='Thinkpad T420', student=null}}
Student{studentId=6, firstname='Erika', lastname='Samson', email='erika.samson@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@3635099, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=4, manufacturer='Hewlett Packard', model='Envy 17', student=null}}
Student{studentId=7, firstname='Carola', lastname='Walker', email='carola.walker@mailbox.org', term=entities.Term@1da1380b, laptop=Laptop{laptopId=6, manufacturer='Dell', model='XPS 15', student=null}}
```

The parent entity:

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Laptop laptop;
```

and the child entity;

```java
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "laptop")
private Student student;
```

Hopefully there's someone out there which can help me.

So far,
Daniel

Comment: How is the database schema generated? If it is not autogenerated by hibernate, please post the schema.

Comment: Its auto generated.

Comment: Can you add the code how you save, retrive and print records?

Comment: Of course I can:

```java
tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Student");
        List<Student> students = query.getResultList();

        students.forEach(student -> {
            System.out.println(student);
        });

        tx.commit();
````

Answer (score 1):

In the student class do the following:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Laptop laptop;
```

As you want to store the laptop automatically along with Student details.

Comment: This is most likely not the problem since the relation is persisted (the owning side is the `Student`/parent) and loaded from the the parent-side.

Comment: Have you tried using @JoinColumn on owning side of the relation i.e. Student.

Comment: I have not tried anything so far, I am still waiting for OP to clarify on the database schema. But the join column seems not to be the problem aswell since - again - the data is correclty fetche from the owning side.

Comment: meanwhile check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415046/11390623

Comment: rishi if tried it like you suggested it but without any effect, there's still no foreignkey column in the laptop table and the field is still null. Also tried already to add at both sides (parent/child entities) an @JoinColumn also without any effects. And rishi the solution, which is mentioned in your linked topic, I've already tried, also without any effects. :/

Comment: @DanielTran "*there's still no foreignkey column in the laptop table...*" - There never should be! The foreign key is defined on the `Student` table and only on the student table. This information is sufficient for a 1:1 relation.

Comment: Okay, but it still would be nice, to have the property student filled in the Laptop class.